# how to calculate length of journey using bearings?

Tags: trigonometry

A boat leaves a port and sails 7km on a bearing of 050 degrees. It then sails 9km on a bearing of 150 degrees. The boat then returns to port. How far is the journey home?.

please help i'm stuck on bearings!!, internal soon not sure if its relevant but obviously will need to know it anyway.

already tried 
$$a^2+b^2=c^2\\
9^2+b^2=7^2\\
81+b^2=49\\
b^2=81-49\\
b^2= 32\\
b=4\sqrt2\ \ km $$

but I checked the answers in the book and it equals 10.4km 
I just don't know how to get that answer.

Comment: Bearings are typically angles turned clockwise from North. Using the info given, you can sketch a triangle with two sides and the angle between them known. Then use Law of Cosines to get the missing side.

Comment: could you please explain the formula you use because i'm quite confused. thanks. @JohnHabert

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the Law of Cosines which states that $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos C$, where $a,b,c$ are the sides of any triangle and $C$ is the angle opposite side $c$. Using the information given in the problem, the triangle we sketch (below) has sides $a=7$, $b=9$ and $c$ to be found for the answer.

[image: Sketch of triangle formed by problem statement]
$ $

With a little geometry knowledge, we see that $m\angle C = 80^{\circ}$. So we get that $c^2 = 7^2+9^2-2*7*9*\cos(80^{\circ}) \approx 108.12 \Longrightarrow c \approx 10.398$

Comment: Nice graph.  It might be useful to explain how you got the $50^o + 30^o = 80^o$.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the vectors and take the norm.

$\|7(\cos 50°, \sin 50°) + 9(\cos 150°, \sin 150°)\| \approx 10.398$.

Comment: sorry, could you explain how I format the full solution because its marked on working out also. I sort of understand it though thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: the full equation?, like (a^2 + b^2 or the formula that you would put into a calculator.) @copper.hat

Comment: Compute $7 \cos 50°$, etc, This gives you two pairs $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, then add them (pairwise) to get another pair $(z_1,z_2)$. Now compute the length $\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2}$.